# Calculate a value in an object without creating a class

Tags: javascript

I have some raw data in an object. One of the properties needs to be calculated with parameters from some other properties.

This is not working obviously:

```
var myObj = {
  val1: 3,
  val2: 5,
  sum: this.val1 + this.val2 //NaN
}
```

I'm aware I can create a class and then an instance. Have done it here: http://jsbin.com/AtaQOPUM/1/edit?js,console,output

But isn't there a way where I don't have to do like this? My object is about 150 rows. I have to insert all that in the constructor and then duplicate the object. It will be 300 rows instead of 150.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can't access the object inside of itself. If you don't want to instantiate it, you will need to directly add the property later:

```
var myObj = {
    val1: 3,
    val2: 5,
}

myObj.sum = myObj.val1 + myObj.val2 // = 8
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/h265h/)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply make a function that appends the required parameters:

```
 var Append = function(obj) { obj.sum = obj.a + obj.b; return obj }
 var myObj = Append({ a:1, b: 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

A *function as an object* might better suit your needs here :

```
  function myObj() {

       this.val1 = 3;
       this.val2 = 5;
       this.sum = this.val1+this.val2;

    }

   var newsum = new myObj();

   console.log(newsum.sum);
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Those parameters only ever exist when `myObj()` is instantiated. Perhaps the object is being used as a data store, rather than what we'd traditionally think of as a class? Without instantiating the object, there's no access to `val1`, `val2` or `sum`.

Comment: Without declaring 'myObj' there is no access to those values either. Same difference. The question is, "One of the properties needs to be calculated with parameters from some other properties." - and the OP talks about 'classes'- this is as close as javascript gets to a class. Note my use of 'might' as not knowing the full context.

Comment: Sorry, it's not the same difference. By the very nature of the fact that you're using `this`, your example actually manipulates the value for the generated objects of `myObj()`, but not of `myObj()` directly. The OP states he's aware of this solution, but wants to modify them directly in the object...

Comment: an object created by 'new' is as good as an object stated literally. This example is to show how the OP can use 'this' within a correct context.

Comment: No. `this` no longer refers to `myObj`, but rather to `newsum`. The OP is (as far as I can tell) asking how to create `myObj.sum`, not `newsum.sum`...

Comment: No what ? it is not as good ? depends on what the job is. newsum is an object created from myObj   all good stuff. As long as he user1572526 is happy. this is pointless.

Comment: I agree. However, please read the title of the question: *Calculate a value in an object **without creating a class***

Comment: "A function as an object might better suit your needs here :" is my headline - sometimes it's good for folks to see other ways ( in case they don't know them ) - you must have hit questions on here that ask for something which might not be exactly what they want, just doing that. no harm no foul

Comment: eg: "Calculate a value in an object" - so showing a function as an **object** -

Comment: You've shown a function as a class... `newsum` is the object, `myObj` is the class...

Comment: nope, not really, sorry fella, im trying to show that even an object literal could be consider a class ( by some) , especially if it contains dynamic values , and that to say, 'without  creating a class' is a somewhat blurry statement to use for javascript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44496/discussion-between-benm-and-rob-sedgwick)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `this` in

```
var myObj = {
  val1: 3,
  val2: 5,
  sum: this.val1 + this.val2 //NaN
}
```

is not the object itself but the window (checked with console)

You have to perform the initialisation outside of the object creation itself:

```
var myObj = {
  val1: 3,
  val2: 5
};

myObj.sum = myObj.val1 + myObj.val2;
```

**EDIT:** 
Ignore whatever's below, I accidentally set the object before in my console during testing.
*Instead use the object name itself:
    var myObj = {
      val1: 3,
      val2: 5,
      sum: myObj["val1"] + myObj["val2"] //8
    }*

Comment: -1. This does not work. It produces `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val1' of undefined` > http://jsfiddle.net/h265h/1/

Comment: That somehow seemed to work on my console :O I think I set the myObj previously, and reset it again...